# Fastest way to discriminate values in JSON by a nested value for large JSON files

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file (the largest file available [here](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html), 13.2 GB). Here's an example of the format:

```
{
  "head_templates": [
    {
      "args": {
        "1": "ast",
        "2": "adverb",
        "head": ""
      },
      "expansion": "más o menos",
      "name": "head"
    },
    {
      "args": {},
      "expansion": "más o menos",
      "name": "ast-adv"
    }
  ],
  "lang": "Asturian",
  "lang_code": "ast",
  "pos": "adv",
  "senses": [
    {
      "categories": [
        "Asturian adverbs",
        "Asturian lemmas",
        "Asturian multiword terms"
      ],
      "glosses": [
        "more or less (approximately)"
      ],
      "raw_glosses": [
        "more or less (approximately)"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "word": "más o menos"
}

{
  "categories": [
    "Spanish adverbs",
    "Spanish lemmas",
    "Spanish multiword terms",
    "Spanish terms with IPA pronunciation"
  ],
  "head_templates": [
    {
      "args": {},
      "expansion": "más o menos",
      "name": "es-adv"
    }
  ],
  "lang": "Spanish",
  "lang_code": "es",
  "pos": "adv",
  "related": [
    {
      "word": "quien más quien menos"
    }
  ],
  "senses": [
    {
      "categories": [
        "Spanish terms with usage examples"
      ],
      "examples": [
        {
          "english": "It's approximately ten dollars.",
          "text": "Es más o menos diez dólares.",
          "type": "example"
        }
      ],
      "glosses": [
        "give or take, more or less, approximately; pretty much"
      ],
      "raw_glosses": [
        "give or take, more or less, approximately; pretty much"
      ],
      "synonyms": [
        {
          "word": "aproximadamente"
        },
        {
          "word": "cerca de"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "glosses": [
        "so-so (neither good nor bad)"
      ],
      "raw_glosses": [
        "so-so (neither good nor bad)"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sounds": [
    {
      "ipa": "/ˌmas o ˈmenos/"
    },
    {
      "ipa": "[ˌmas o ˈme.nos]"
    }
  ],
  "word": "más o menos"
}
```

The format above is has sub-entries for each language (in this case two, `"Asturian"` and `"Spanish"`. Within the `"Spanish"` entry, I want to capture the `"word"` and store it in a list *ONLY* if `"Spanish multiword terms"` appears in the categories for the Spanish entry. What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: Grab a SAX-style JSON parser and have it operate on the file input stream, then check whether your conditions are met for each new object.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to handling JSON. Many thanks for your reply. Which parser would you recommend for this task? @LMD

Comment: try https://pypi.org/project/ijson/

Comment: Tried ijson, for element in ijson.parse(input_file): doesnt seem to work...

Comment: ijson looks decent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your data, it doesn't look like a properly formatted json. Rather more like one json object per line (it's also written in your [link](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html)).

From there you can loop over your file lines and extract the desired values:

```
import json

word_list = []
with open("D:\\raw-wiktextract-data.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        tmp = json.loads(line)
        if any("Spanish multiword terms" in s.get('categories', []) for s in tmp.get('senses', [])):
            word_list.append(tmp.get('word', ''))
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. I figured this out shortly after and forgot to update the post  Your solution was faster than mine though. Many thanks and have a good day.
Edit: Why did you create a temporary variable? My guess is that it's faster than having to reindex many times.

Comment: What do you mean with reindexing? assigning a temporary variable makes the code easier to read. You could as well write `json.loads(line).get('senses', [])` in the comprehension